# Steps to solve parametric equation of Folium of Descartes

Tags: parametric

I know that the parametric equations of the Folium of Descartes are $\displaystyle x = \frac{3t}{(1+t)^3} $and $\displaystyle y = \frac{3t^2}{(1+t)^3}$. What are the steps to achieve this parametric equation from the given equation $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$, given that $\displaystyle t= \frac yx$? How do I substitute the t value to get this parametric equation?

Comment: You do appreciate that there is something arbitary about a prarmeterisation. Eg $x^2+y^2=1$ could be parameterised by $( \cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ or $(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$.

Comment: @sue with $t=\frac{y}{x}$ obtain $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $y=tx$ we get
$$x^3+t^3x^3=3x^2t$$ for $x\neq 0$ we get
$$x(1+t^3)=3t$$ therefore $$x=\frac{3t}{1+t^3}$$ from here we get easy $$y=\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $t=\frac{y}{x}$ into the first equation, we get:
\begin{align*}
x=\frac{3t}{1+t^3}&\implies x=\frac{3\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{1+\frac{y^3}{x^3}}\\
&\implies x=\frac{3x^2y}{x^3+y^3}\\
&\implies x^3+y^3=3xy\\
\end{align*}